# Rails 3 gem installed with bundler, still get NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I'm trying to install the calendar_helper gem. I included the gem in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'calendar_helper'
```

I ran bundle install and loaded fine.

```
Using calendar_helper (0.2.4)
```

0.2.4 is the newest version in GitHub, so that looks good. I'm running on Pow so I don't need to restart the server (though I tried that anyway). Adding a call to the method calendar throws an error:

```
undefined method `calendar'
```

I feel like something could be wrong with my Rails installation or something. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like version 0.2.4 is up-to-date with what's on github; it's missing the subclass of Rails::Engine necessary to load the helper. The key line on the edge source is here: https://github.com/topfunky/calendar_helper/blob/master/lib/calendar_helper.rb#L231.

You may be able to fix this by installing the gem from edge:

```
gem 'calendar_helper', :git => 'git://github.com/topfunky/calendar_helper.git'
```

Edited:

If that still isn't working, you can also try this in your ApplicationHelper:

```
require 'calendar_helper'

module ApplicationHelper
  include CalendarHelper
end
```

Comment: Really good investigative work! Unfortunately, it still isn't working for me.. Is there another easy way to include this gem? It's a one class gem, and I just want to use that method calendar! Thanks a million for your help. :)

Comment: Ahh, thank you so much, that worked! I'm curious why bundling the gem didn't solve it but... at least it's working. Thanks! :)

Comment: It may also work to call `require 'calendar_helper'` in an initializer without doing the explicit `include`

Comment: I finally figured out the root of this problem. It *was* my Pow server. I'm using Rails so I thought it was reloading everything on each page load. Turns out that it doesn't automatically reload the environment. Such touching tmp/restart.txt actually is required when updating the bundle. Anyway, thanks for your help, I appreciate it!